# Install local wheel file with requirements.txt

Tags: python, requirements.txt

Have a local package  `ABC-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl`. I want to install it in the different project through requrements.txt.  e.g.

requirements.txt

```
ABC==0.0.2
Flask==1.1.2
flask-restplus==0.13.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

Is it possible to install the ABC package this way. `ABC-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl` is included in source code. I had to `pip install ABC-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl` separately.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is called a [direct reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references). Since version 19.3, [pip support this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#description:~:text=pip%20also%20supports%20installing%20from%20%E2%80%9Crequirements%20files%E2%80%9D%2C) in both command line and requirement files. Check out [an example](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example) from the official documentation.

As to OP's question, simply put the local wheel's relative path, i.e., `./<my_wheel_dir>/<my_wheel.whl>`, in `requirement.txt`, e.g.,

```
./local_wheels/ABC-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Flask==1.1.2
flask-restplus==0.13.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

Comment: Old answer, things may have changed since then. Now that I try this method, it works if I run:

"pip install -r requirements.txt"

- But if I instead try installing like:

"pip install ."

- Or try to build a wheel:

"python setup.py bdist_wheel"

- In these both cases I get error from that "direct reference" line:

"Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier"

Comment: @jarmniku I still use this approach, and it works well. The question is about how to install a local package through `requirement.txt`. The solution does exactly that and of course nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

With a `pyproject.toml` file using setuptools the local syntax `./local_wheels/ABC-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl` does not work.

This works:

```
tensorflow @ file://localhost/pip-wheels/aarch64/tensorflow-2.8.4-cp38-cp38-linux_aarch64.whl
```

`file://localhost/` + absolute paths is needed.

The [pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6658) migth explain why.

Answer (score 0):

in your `requirement.txt` file add

`-f <path to the whl file with file name>==<Version>`

then install using `python -m pip install -r <path to requirement.txt file>`

Comment: Flat out didn't work.

What *does* work is

-f <path to local whl file>
<wheel-package-name>==<wheel version>

The -f just tells it where to find a candidate wheel... it doesn't actually install anything.

Comment: I found <wheel-package-name>==<wheel version> needs to be on its own line as well