# How to install custom Python package and run with Azure Machine Learning job?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to train my model with an Azure Machine Learning job.

However, I run the job as an CLI app (with Click), where I import some functions from other files.
In my CI/CD pipeline I install that custom package with

`pip install .`

However, when the job is created in Azure ML, it cannot import those functions.
It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlops_i4t/machine_learning/model_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mlops_i4t.preprocessing import get_final_dataframe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlops_i4t'
```

How can I pip install a custom package and use it in an Azure ML job?

Comment: You might need environments (setup either programatically or manually) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-environments

Comment: @superfuzzy Yes I saw that, however where can I provide something like: pip install ...? I only can set predefined environments like "AzureML-sklearn-0.24-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu@latest",

Comment: I usually have a helper script in my repo that is basically `run_in_azure.py`. Have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-set-up-training-targets on how to set that up

Answer (score 0):

**Edit on more complex setups (like your own package)**

Create your own docker file, e.g.:

```py
dockerfile = r"""
    FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.02-py3

    RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

    RUN pip install numpy .....
    COPY requirements.azure.txt .
    RUN pip install -r requirements.azure.txt
    ....
    """

    myEnv = Environment(name = "your-env-name")
    myEnv.docker.base_image = None
    myEnv.docker.base_dockerfile = dockerfile
    myEnv.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
    myEnv.docker.arguments= ['--privileged']
    myEnv.register(workspace=ws)
```

See below on how to use this `myEnv`.

---

I assume you know about ScriptRunConfig and similar (otherwise see my comment)

Then the way I typically set up my environment is:

```py
    myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(
        name="your-env-name", 
        file_path="requirements.azure.txt"
    )
    
    # Specify a (GPU) base image
    myenv.docker.enabled = True
    myenv.docker.base_image = (
        "mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.1-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04"
    )
    
    # Either go with RunConfiguration (more general)
    train_run_config = RunConfiguration()
    train_run_config.environment = myenv
    ....

    # OR use the simpler ScriptRunConfig:
    run_config = ScriptRunConfig(
        source_directory=".",
        command=launch_cmd,
        compute_target=compute,
        environment=myenv,
    )
```

The docker image serves as a base, you can build your own or pick from azures defaults.

The crucial part is the from_pip_requirements
I typically store my requirements in a separate `requirements.azure.txt` since my local install e.g. might not have a GPU, etc

Here you can also use pip to install prepackaged wheels of your local install. [Install local wheel file with requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956690/install-local-wheel-file-with-requirements-txt)

I really hope this makes it clear now :) Otherwise feel free to leave some comment.

Comment: Yes it does, but I only now understand where to put pip packages (e.g. Pandas, SKlearn). However I am still confused how to install your private custom Python package? Maybe an idea is to push that as a Docker image and use as the environment?

Comment: You can either use the power of pip (did not test this though): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956690/install-local-wheel-file-with-requirements-txt
Or you can as you said build your own docker image (what I normally do). Apart from solving your problem this also makes everything easier because you only have to worry about docker, not azure

Comment: I tried to create an env from a Dockerfile. However I think the error is because I provide that environment in a command, but it expects azure.ai.ml.entities._assets.environment.Environment

So I think I need to switch to a ScriptRunConfig class

Comment: try it out :) also don't forget to `COPY . .` to be able to successfully build your package

Comment: I tried, but now I get an error when building the Docker image. It says: 

Step 4/28 : COPY requirements.txt .
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat ./requirements.txt: file does not exist

Any suggestions? I guess it is because the source dir is within my package.

    src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory="./src/mlops_i4t",
                          script="train.py",
                          compute_target=computeName,
                          environment=env)

Comment: yes you most likely need to `COPY src/requirements.txt .`, like you need the relative path from the dockerfile to your requirements txt